# Extending 'isalnum' to recognize UTF-8 umlaut

Tags: c++, utf-8

I wrote a function which extends `isalnum` to recognize UTF-8 coded umlaut.

Is there maybe a more elegant way to solve this issue?

The code is as follows:

```
bool isalnumlaut(const char character) {
    int cr = (int) (unsigned char) character;
    if (isalnum(character)
            || cr == 195 // UTF-8
            || cr == 132 // Ä
            || cr == 164 // ä
            || cr == 150 // Ö
            || cr == 182 // ö
            || cr == 156 // Ü
            || cr == 188 // ü
            || cr == 159 // ß
    ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tested my solution now several times, and it seems to do the job for my purpose though. Any strong objections?

Comment: UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding. There are several dozen umlauts in Unicode. In particular, Unicode has a "stand-alone" unlaut, U+0308. It adds an umlaut to the preceding character. I.e. U+0041 U+0308 is Ä. Also, why is  ß in that list? That doesn't have an umlaut.

Comment: @MSalters I think you mean combining, and not "stand-alone".  (And officially, it's a "diaeresis", rather than an "Umlaut"---the word "Umlaut" refers to its effect on pronunciation in German.)  Unicode has both a combining diaeresis and a spacing diaeresis (U+00A8), plus around 80 "pre-combined" characters using a diaeresis.  (Results of `grep DIAERESIS UnicodeData.txt`.)

Comment: @James: of course. But given the phrasing of the question, I didn't use the formal terms. BTW, you might also have included "diaeresis below" (U+0324) in that count, as well as the precomposed uses such as Ṳ U+1E72

Comment: @MSalters I know.  The only thing I was really wondering about was "stand-alone" (which to me means the opposite of combining).  The rest was just additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you're claiming.

The utf-8 representation of `Ä` is two bytes - `0xC3,0x84`. A lone byte with a value above `0x7F` is meaningless in utf-8.

---

Some general suggestions:

- Unicode is large. Consider using a library that has already handled the issues you're seeing, such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).
- It doesn't often make sense for a function to operate on a single *code unit* or *code point*. It makes much more sense to have functions that operate on either ranges of code points or single *glyphs* (see [here](http://unicode.org/glossary) for definitions of those terms).
- Your concept of alpha-numeric is likely to be underspecified for a character set as large as the Universal Character Set; do you want to treat the characters in the Cyrillic alphabet as alphanumerics? Unicode's concept of what is alphabetic may not match yours - especially if you haven't considered it.

Comment: Unicode actually goes to great lengths to specify the alphanumeric properties of each and every character. In particular, the Unicode character categories `Alphabetic` and `Numeric_Type` (from UAX #44) would reasonably cover `isalnum()`.

Comment: @MSalters: Good point. I've cleared up the langauge to make it explicit that it's the OP's understanding of alpha-numeric that's likely to be underspecified.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but the C++ `std::isalnum` in `<locale>` almost certainly recognizes locale specific additional characters: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isalnum/

Comment: The `std::isalnum` function doesn't work for multibyte encodings like UTF-8.  Regardless of the locale.  Just looking at one `char` isn't sufficient.  You have to look at the entire character (which can take up to four `char` in UTF-8).

Comment: Even 4 chars might not be enough depending on how he wants to handle combining characters.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible with the interface you define, since UTF-8 is a
multibyte encoding; a single character requires multiple `char` to
represent it.  (I've got code for determining whether a UTF-8 is a
member of a specified set of characters in my library, but the 
character is specified by a pair of iterators, and not a single `char`.)